# Open Graph url gets messed up on a users timeline?

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

When I like an URL on the company website:
http://guidepal.com/escape/10

The link that gets liked into the timeline looks like this:

=">http://guidepal.com/escape/10?fb_action_ids=10151400567746110&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=timeline_og&action_object_map=%7B%2210151400567746110%22%3A10151100366393350%7D&action_type_map=%7B%2210151400567746110%22%3A%22og.likes%22%7D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D&code=AQB2NUbRhNvppL1HOqmJM6CBGQa1N3vUoK9QrPNNm516895czzIFYn93tiT4HWmBcCCrjK8tYvHqUPLAbu4mhk-xT3w17UMeTITQGnJXW3_NuyYc1Aa7FHl0nTwyuYzDS05x761boSwsGNoOpcL-ulsmiiVObacATa2NQEjLtQFrygJ81fHrSyr7pF5WWlPsf9w#*=*

The URL is there but there seems to be a problem, since it's adding some more stuff (which I really hope is not an access token there somewhere :P).
I'm guessing there is something wrong with the meta tags, but I have no idea what since everything seems to be okay.

Any ideas?

Comment: No, that’s just stuff Facebook adds to links, for tracking purposes. Nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually investigated this a bit further and this actually is because what is happening on the server side. I'm not responsible for the web-page here, but the one who is, explained that there are some bits of code that handles integer at the end of an url, he would not thought it would be a problem.
Weirdly enough it works by pressing the image instead of the URL in the recent activity.

And a hard problem to know when you are not responsible for both.

Answer (score 0):

I've just liked it, and the URL came up correctly on my Timeline.

It also looks like the meta tags are set up correctly - you can check them on the [linter tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://guidepal.com/escape/10) that Facebook provides

Comment: it seems that clicking the link only affects me for some strange reason. Thx for your time and helping.